# VimScript: generated syntax highlights. Make feedkeys() silent

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I have written a function in VimScript where I, based on some calculations, want to set-up **many** syntax region for different sections of my text file.
In the following example, I highlight from line 5, column 108 to line 8, column 10

```
:syntax region Red start="\%108c\%5l" end="\%10c\%8l"
```

The VimScipt code I use looks like this:

```
call feedkeys(':syntax region Red start="\%' . col0 . 'c\%' . lin0 . 'l" end="\%' . col1 . 'c\%' . lin1 . 'l"' . "\<cr>")
```

This works as intended, but generates **a lot** of output, because feedkeys echoes what it does. This echoing makes my code **very** slow.

My question:

Is there a way to make feedkeys() silent, or can this be done without feedkeys()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you use `feedkeys()` in the first place? That function is only useful for simulating key presses which is not needed here.

You must use `:execute` to execute a command pieced from several expressions:

```
execute 'syntax region Red start="\%'.col0.'c\%'.lin0.'l" end="\%'.col1.'c\%'.lin1.'l"'
```

Note: spacing removed to make the whole command fit without scrolling.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!